# Is it possible to generate and execute Python code in a Python script? [Dynamic Python code]

Tags: dynamic, code-generation, python

I am working on some reports (counts) and I have to fetch counts for different parameters. Pretty simple but tedious.

A sample query for one parameter :

```
qCountsEmployee = (
    "select count(*) from %s where EmployeeName is not null"
     % (tablename)
     )
CountsEmployee = execute_query(qCountsEmployee)
```

Now I have few hundred such parameters!

What I did was : create a list of all the parameters and generate them using a quick Python script and then copy that text and put it in the main script to avoid the tedious lines.

```
columnList = ['a', 'b', ............'zzzz']

for each in columnList:
   print (
            'q' + each + ' ='
            + '"select count(*) from %s where' + each
            + 'is not null" % (tablename)'
         )
   print each + '   = execute_query(' + 'q' + each + ')'
```

While this approach works, I was wondering if instead of a separate script to generate lines of code and copy paste into main program, can I generate them in the main script directly and let the script treat them as lines of code? That will make the code much more readable is what I think. Hope I made sense! Thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be possible, but is not useful here.

Just do something like

```
columnList = ['a', 'b', ............'zzzz']

results = {}
for column in columnList:
    query = (
            "select count(*) from " + tablename
            + " where " + column + " is not null"
            )
    result = execute_query(qCountsEmployee)
    results[column] = result
```

You as well can put all this together in a generator function and do

```
def do_counting(column_list):
    for column in column_list:
        query = (
            "select count(*) from " + tablename
            + " where " + column + " is not null"
            )
        result = execute_query(qCountsEmployee)
        yield column, result

result_dict = dict(do_counting(['...']))
```

Comment: Can you please explain your generator solution?

Comment: It iterates over the contents of the given list and yields a 2-tuple for each item. These 2-tuples are then [put together into a dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
cmd = compile( 'a = 5', '<string>', 'exec' )
exec( cmd )
```

That is the same as just writing:

```
a = 5
```

The string passed as the first argument to compile can be built dynamically.

Comment: While I love the one-liner (or 2), applying this to my query and quotes is kinda confusing. Will try and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and try it, but exec() is evil.  You should do as glglgl suggests and write a program that does what you want without dynamic code.

Comment: Thank you, I take your exec is evil suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

To build on what glglgl said, you are probably better with dynamic SQL than dynamic Python (though Dynamic Python is definitely possible using things like [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) ).  When working with Dynamic SQL, you should be careful of sql injection.  It seems like it would not come up in your particular use-case, but it certainly comes up more often than many developers realize.

I happen to have written an article about [SQL Injection and Python](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-injection-defense-in-depth/) which is available at [Simple-talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-injection-defense-in-depth/).